# Renovations IN/ON the backyard

Tags: prepositions

On the phrase:

> Next week, renovations **on** the backyard will be made.

is the correct preposition "on" or "in"?

Answer (score 2):

"Renovations *on* your backyard" mean that the backyard will be improved.

"Renovations *in* your backyard means that is the location of the renovation. While that usually means the backyard is being renovated, it is conceivable that the renovations are being done to something nearby, such as a tool shed, the rear of the house, or a fence along a neighbour's yard, which don't affect the backyard but require work to be done there.

"On" is the more precise version (telling you what is being renovated) but "in" is used, too (to talk about the location of the renovation).

Comment: True, but we can also say: Backyard renovations will be carried out.

Answer (score 0):

#### Let's say I have an old garage with an old car inside it.

> Renovations will be done **on** the car.

This means the car will be renovated.

> Renovations will be done **on** the garage.

This means the garage will be renovated.

> Renovations will be done **in** the garage.

This sentence is ambiguous. It could mean we are renovating the car while it's inside the garage, but it could also mean we are renovating the inside of the garage.

> Renovations will be done **to** the garage.

This means the garage will be renovated, but these renovations could be on the outside of the garage (for example, a new roof) or on the inside (for example, new paint on the walls).

> Renovations will be done **in** the car.

This means the interior of the car will be renovated (for example, repairing the seat upholstery, not repainting the fenders or replacing the bumpers).